# Crashlytics/Fabric alternative for pure java applications

Tags: java, monitoring, crashlytics

since I was unable to google anything useful, and there is always someone smarter on the other side of the ethernet cable, I'd like to ask:

Is there some service that provides a similar functionality to Fabric/Crashlytics but for pure Java applications?

I know there are some technical limitations that you can't easily overcome, but it still seems that at least the core principle (catch the exception, report it to a server and then propagate it further) should be doable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of Java logging frameworks (java.util.logging, log4j, etcetera) that do most if not all of what crashlytics does.

- You can log exceptions and other noteworthy events.  (Whether the exception propagates further is up to the catch block that makes the logger call ...)
- You can write log events to local log files, rotate logfiles, etcetera.  The files can be copied to a central server for safe-keeping.
- You can also send log events to a remote logging server; e.g. using the syslog service on Unix / Linux systems.

The log files / log events can be hooked up to monitoring frameworks (Nagios, CheckMK, etcetera) to check for specific problems and alert a person.

I'm sure there are other open source and commercial tools in this space ... though I've never gone looking.

Comment: I disagree. Crashlytics sends the crashes neatly to your phone, without you having to setup anything. It's great for small home-made server apps. For traditional Java logging frameworks you have to program at least the support for mailing those stacktraces to you.